# numpy how to do bulk operation on every element of the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bulk

I've a numpy array

```
[
 [1,5,6],
 [10,12,20]
]
```

I want to do an operation on every element of the array that, takes the current element value and does an operation. A sort of bulk operation like the np.square function.

i.e. x = (x + 1) * 2
the result would be:

```
[
 [4,12,14],
 [22,26,42]
]
```

I know I can do a for loop for every element and apply the operation but I want more compact syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [
    [1, 5, 6],
    [10, 12, 20]
]

lst = np.array(lst)
lst = (lst + 1) * 2
print(lst)
```

Which outputs, as desired:

```
[[ 4 12 14]
 [22 26 42]]
```

if at the end you want it to be a list you may convert it back, but `np` arrays are great.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using numpy vectorize:

```
# define numpy array
arr = np.array([
 [1,5,6],
 [10,12,20]
])

# create function
func = np.vectorize(lambda x: (x + 1) * 2)

# apply function to array
func(arr)
```